# How does aggregation across time bring about feedback?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, aggregation, univariate

On page 11 [Pankratz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471615285) says: "Sometimes there is sound theoretical reasoning in favor of a one-way relationship from the inputs to the output (no feedback). But even then it is important to have a test procedure to detect feedback. Why? Because statistical feedback may exist, even when the underlying system is one way, if the data are aggregated across time... there might be feedback even though there may not be any direct causal mechanism..." To clarify, in the following simple Dynamic Linear Model $$Y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1X_t+\epsilon_t$$ he calls $X_t$ *input* and $Y_t$ *output* and *feedback* refers to the effect of $Y_t$ or $Y_{t-1}$ or $Y_{t-2}$ ... on $X_t$.

By *aggregation* the author refers to going from say monthly data to say yearly data. Take $X_t$ to be GDP and $Y_t$ to be the sales of a tiny mom-and-pop store. As I understand it, the author says that in the regression $Y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1X_t+\epsilon_t$ there would be no feedback from the sales of the tiny mom-and-pop store to GDP with monthly data but that there may be feedback with annual data.

I find this very intriguing. Can someone elucidate how time aggregation can cause feedback in the absence of a causal mechanism? Whether or not there is feedback is crucial as it determines whether a univariate or a multivariate model is appropriate.

Comment: I wonder exactly what you mean by "aggregated across time."  To me that would mean you are creating new data of the form $Y^\prime_t=f(Y_{t-s},Y_{t-s+1},\ldots,Y_t)$ for some function $f$ (with fixed $s$) and similarly (perhaps with a different function and different $s$) for the $X.$ If, then, "feedback" means $Y^\prime_t$ is associated with $X^\prime_{t+1},$ that's just an obvious result of the aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. By aggregation he refers to going from say monthly data to say yearly data. Take $X_t$ to be GDP and $Y_t$ to be the sales of a tiny mom-and-pop store. As I understand it, the author says that in the regression $Y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 X_t+\epsilon_t$ there would be no feedback from the sales of the tiny mom-and-pop store to GDP with monthly data but that there may be feedback with annual data. That is surprising to me and very consequential as it determines whether a univariate model is appropriate.

Comment: Very likely in monthly model you have a very strong seasonal effect of $X_{t-12}$ and below, that you have not considered. Typically such effects disappear after aggregation, that is roughly summation, in your case, but if it is a complex time varying seasonal pattern, it may be preserved as AR after aggregation. Maybe this paper will  help https://www.bancaditalia.it/pubblicazioni/temi-discussione/2008/2008-0685/index.html?com.dotmarketing.htmlpage.language=1

Comment: @DmitrijCelov: thank you; this is a wonderful reference; it will take me some time to read it; but I will be back once I've read it